# How to rename invoke url in api in aws console?

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I want to make our url more user friendly. I created a new hosted zone, requested a certificate for a domain name (the certificate's been issued, but validation is pending, it's been pending for a couple hours now). I believe my next step would be create a custom domain name.
How long usually it takes for a certificate to get validated?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is more about certificate validation than renaming invokation URL then I suggest you to change this topic title.

Regarding the certificate validation: it depends on the solution you are using and what steps you have already performed. I'm assuming that you are using:

- `AWS Certificate Manager` for issuing certificates
- DNS as validation method

After requesting the certificate you are supposed to [validate it by adding some CNAME records in your DNS zone](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/security/easier-certificate-validation-using-dns-with-aws-certificate-manager/). You can do that in a couple of clicks if you are using `AWS Route53` for your DNS zone management (if not then you'll need to perform more steps, depending on your provider). More generally if you click on your certificate request you'll get details about why it is pending.

For information, so far it always took me a couple of minutes for getting my certificates validated.